# Как вывести данные из MongoDB в таблицу vue-tables-2 (Express, Vue, Axios)?

Tags: vue.js, express, axios

Не выходит вывести данные массива в таблицу **vue-tables-2**. 
Хотя строки таблицы генерируются согласно данным массива.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Массив из базы **прилетает успешно.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные на клиенте получаю через **axios**...

```js
import http from "<тут гружу axios>";

export default {

  name: 'customers-list',
  data() {
    return {
      customers: this.customers,
      columns: ['code', 'name', 'status'],
      options: {

        headings: {

          code: 'Key',
          name: 'Model',
          status: 'Status'
        },
        sortable: ['code', 'name', 'status'],
        filterable: ['code', 'name', 'status']
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {

    retrieveCustomers() {

      http
        .get('/customers')
        .then(response => {

          this.customers = response.data;
          console.log(this.customers);
        })
        .catch(e => {

          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {

    this.retrieveCustomers();
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <div class="row">
          <v-client-table :columns="columns" :data="customers" :options="options"></v-client-table>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: вызовите метод `retrieveCustomers` в хуке `created`, а не `mounted` и шаблон отобразите по условию (после получения данных с сервера)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При объявлении модели:

```
data() {
  return {
    customers: [],
    filterable: ['key', 'model', 'status'],

    // остальные поля по такому же принципу
    // вместо   ['code', 'name', 'status']
  }
}
```

Можете также добавить условие отображения дочернего компонента:

```
<v-client-table v-if="customers.length" ...></v-client-table>
```